# Can two profile types be created with one role?

Tags: 7, users

I have created two profile types *Self Employee* and *Salaried Employee* for the role *Employee*.

I want to present these profile forms inside the user account edit form. For that, I'm using the [Account Profile module](https://www.drupal.org/project/account_profile). However, it's only showing the *Self employee* form.

Is it possible to show multiple profiles for role?

Comment: https://www.drupal.org/project/account_profile

Comment: So what is the question? You're not clearly stated the problem.

Comment: The question is can two profile types be created with one role drupal 7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, with Account Profile, multiple profiles can be embedded for given role. In order to make this happen, you need to:

1. Make sure both profile types have the *Show this profile as part of user account form.* checked on profile settings page (i.e. the edit links in **/admin/structure/profiles**).
2. Make sure the role in question has both the *Edit own profile* & *View own profile* permissions set for each profile type.